# Custom Internal Server Error Message Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, error-handling, playframework-2.0

In play framework, every time you get an Internal Server Error (500) in production mode, the browser shows a web page with

> Oops, an error occured, This exception has been logged with id XXXX

I would like to customize the error message (or at least translate it to spanish), keeping the error id that makes it easier to look for in the application log.

I've tried to configure an error page in the Global settings in JAVA like this:

```
public Promise<Result> onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable t) {
    return Promise.<Result>pure(internalServerError(
            views.html.error.render(t)
    ));
}
```

Where I've a view named error.scala.html.

It is not working right now, it does not show any errors, just ignores it. Also with this alternative, I don't know how to display the error id.

I appreciate any suggestions, thanks a lot.

Comment: Where did you put your `Global.java`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `Global` class in the root package? That's a quite common mistake and also the reason why it is ignored.

Comment: Yes my Global.java is in the root package and what seems a bit strange is that I have a onStart and a filters method, and they are working correctly.